# why do I get duplicated items in my listview?

Tags: android, listview

I've checked the array menuItems and it seems good, but there is something wrong in the following code.
When I start it it seems okay but when I start scrolling it gets screwed up and put items on top of the list and duplicates items....it's just weird

```
public class ScoresAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private MainActivity activity;
private ScoreItem[] menuItems;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
ImageDownloader downloader;

public ScoresAdapter(MainActivity a, ScoreItem[] scoreItems) {
    activity = a;
    menuItems = scoreItems;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    downloader = new ImageDownloader();
}

public int getCount() {
    int teller = 0;

    for(int i = 0 ; menuItems.length > i ; i++){
        if(menuItems[i] != null){
            teller++;
        }
    }

    return teller;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {        
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null){    
        if(menuItems[position].getId() == 888){
            //fav header
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scoresheaderfavoriet, null);

        }else if(menuItems[position].getId() == 999){
            //overige header
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scoresheaderoverig, null);

        }else{



            if(menuItems[position].getIsFav()){
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scoresfavitem, null);
            }else{
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scoresitem, null);
            }

            TextView text2=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.position);
            text2.setText(""+ menuItems[position].getPosition());

            TextView text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.name);
            text.setText(menuItems[position].getFirstName() + " " + menuItems[position].getLastName().toUpperCase());

            TextView text5=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.country);
            text5.setText(""+ menuItems[position].getCountry());

            TextView text3=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.score);
            text3.setText(""+ menuItems[position].getScore());

            TextView text8=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.hole);
            text8.setText(""+ menuItems[position].getHole());

            vi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), SpelerView.class);
                    intent.putExtra("id", menuItems[position].getId());
                    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);

                    activity.sluitAlleMenus();
                }
            });
        }


    }



    return vi;
}
}
```

Comment: If convertView is not null you do nothing with it, but you should. convertView - is a recycled item which is out of the screen. You've already passed data to it. So, you should change this data.

Comment: @Jay Biggue if you had solve then post i have same issue

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    CalendarsData c = (CalendarsData) this.getItem(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        convertView = l_Inflater.inflate(R.layout.preference_list_element, null);

        holder.text=(CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkTextView);         
        //holder.tv =(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview);

        holder.text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                CalendarsData ssi = (CalendarsData) cb.getTag();
                ssi.setChecked(cb.isChecked());
            }
        });             

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }   

holder.text.setText("c.anyvalue");
return convertView;
}
```

like the guys above say you need the else:

```
} else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
```

Comment: @PankajAndroid still need help?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once. I think it's because of the adapter's "caching"...You should implement an else like this:

```
 if(convertView==null){
     holder = new NodeViewHolder();
     //Your stuff
     convertView.setTag(holder);
 }else{
     holder = (NodeViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
 }

 public static class NodeViewHolder {
    TextView text;
    TextView text2;
    TextView text3;
    //So on...
 }
```

It'll be executed when the View is cached (not null)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't handling the case when your convertView was NOT null correctly. Change your code like this:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {        
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null){    
        if(menuItems[position].getId() == 888){
            //fav header
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scoresheaderfavoriet, null);

        }else if(menuItems[position].getId() == 999){
            //overige header
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scoresheaderoverig, null);

        }else{



            if(menuItems[position].getIsFav()){
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scoresfavitem, null);
            }else{
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scoresitem, null);
            }


        }


    }
            TextView text2=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.position);
            text2.setText(""+ menuItems[position].getPosition());

            TextView text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.name);
            text.setText(menuItems[position].getFirstName() + " " + menuItems[position].getLastName().toUpperCase());

            TextView text5=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.country);
            text5.setText(""+ menuItems[position].getCountry());

            TextView text3=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.score);
            text3.setText(""+ menuItems[position].getScore());

            TextView text8=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.hole);
            text8.setText(""+ menuItems[position].getHole());

            vi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), SpelerView.class);
                    intent.putExtra("id", menuItems[position].getId());
                    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);

                    activity.sluitAlleMenus();
                }
            });





    return vi;
}
```

That will get you most the way there. You'll likely have to move some of your favorites and/or header footer logic out of the `if(convertView ==null)` as well. I can't exactly tell what you are doing with that though, so I wouldn't know for sure how it needs to be.